# Summing max & min of a list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a homework problem that takes a list of comma separated values, converts them to a list, then sums the max & min from said list.

```
def max_min_sum():
    user_input = input("Please enter a comma seperated list of numbers")
    input_as_a_list = user_input.split(",")
    input_as_numbers = map(float, input_as_a_list)
    print(sum((min(input_as_numbers))+(max(input_as_numbers, default = 0))))
max_min_sum()
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I have also tried:

```
def max_min_sum():
    user_input = input("Please enter a comma seperated list of numbers")
    input_as_a_list = user_input.split(",")
    input_as_numbers = map(float, input_as_a_list) 
    print((min(input_as_numbers) + max(input_as_numbers, default = 0)))    
max_min_sum()
```

But now it's just giving me the min value.

Comment: I tried that but now it's just giving me the min value. Here's the updated code. 

    def max_min_sum():
        user_input = input("Please enter a comma seperated list of numbers")
        input_as_a_list = user_input.split(",")
        input_as_numbers = map(float, input_as_a_list)
        print((min(input_as_numbers) + max(input_as_numbers, default = 0)))
    
    max_min_sum()

Answer (score 1):

You've at least 2 errors in your code, see this fix with the comments:

```
def max_min_sum():
    user_input = input("Please enter a comma seperated list of numbers")
    input_as_a_list = user_input.split(",")
    # map returns a generator, so you need to consume the output first
    # Or, you'll endup with max == 0
    # Or, better using a list comprehension
    # input_as_numbers = [float(elm) for elm in input_as_a_list]
    input_as_numbers = list(map(float, input_as_a_list))
    # No need to use sum, you're already using + operator
    print(min(input_as_numbers)) + max(input_as_numbers, default = 0))

max_min_sum()
```